# html position absolute prevents onclick from clicking

Tags: html, css

I have a button element with a class that has position="absolute". This is preventing the button from being clicked. As soon as I remove the position absolute, the positioning of the button changes to where I don't want it, but the clicking works. The z-index=-1 was intended bc the button lays over another component. How do I get it to keep position absolute AND clickable?

```
<button type="button" onclick="RandomFunction()" class="b-Crown"></button>

.b-Crown {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 15px;
    height: 26px;
    top: -163px;
    left: 265px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #999;
    border-right: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: Remove your `z-index: -1;` ... or make it go on top instead of to bottom. And the reason is positioning, that kicks in when an element is not `static`, the default.

Comment: @LGSon is it due to `position:absolute` which makes the object appear on top/front of the other and `z-index:-1`makes this positioning back again from front.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja Yes, as `z-index` doesn't work if the element doesn't have a `position` other than `static` (or being a flex/grid item)

Comment: Thank you! The z-index:-1;    was on purpose. I wanted this button to be position behind another component. If I change the z-index to 1, I can make a work around and adjust the width to still be able to just see the part I wanted to be displayed. Thank again!

Comment: I have never used `flex` but someway or the other have seen the effect of flex as if the overflow lookalike reaches some optimum flex cuts and displays it inline not sure about flex

Answer (score 3):

Change "`z-index: -1`" to "`z-index: 1`"

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't just drop _"change this to that"_ answers, also explain why it works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess due to `position:absolute` which makes the object appear on top/front of the other and at the same time you are using `z-index:-1` which makes this positioning back again from front. so remove `z-index` if you want the object in front/top else remove `position:absolute` to make it behind the other object

> > Note: the other object should not be static. It depends on the other objects behaviour you have styled as well.

Comment: You can't just say like this, as you don't know what the other element has when it comes to both `position` and `z-index`. Read the first dupe link, it explain how it all works

Comment: So, you are saying if the other object has some positioning defined then absolute will work else static no change like you need to have position:relative to work in sync

Comment: Please read the first dupe link's answer, it explains is well.

Comment: thats correct what i said @LGSon I've read the dupe answer in order to see z-index to take effect you need to have positioning as absolute for the one and opposit relative for the other otherwise theres no point of having only zindex:-1 for the one and +1 for the other

Answer (score 0):

z-index doesn't work on static that's why your button was only clickable if you made the position absolute simply you can remove the z-index or change the position to fixed or relative

> Definition and Usage
>
> The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
>
> An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a >lower stack order.
>
> Note  : z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).